# Does Django render JS on server side?

Tags: django, server-side-rendering

I know that Django has default config of SSR (server-side rendering) but all the articles I have gone through mention that the Django-forms are rendered on server side and then sent to the browser. No specific information on the use case when javascript is mixed in the template.

I want to know if I use jquery tables in my Django template. Does that still render on server side? If yes then how does it render Javascript/jquery on the server-side?

I'd be glad if someone corrects me if my question itself has invalid argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is for browsers so it doesn't matter if you write it in your template or add a link to it. The only way to render JS on the server-side is to actually have an engine doing that for you which Django doesn't.

What Django's template engine does is it will render the template based on the tags and HTML you provided and sends a valid HTML to the user containing the js code or js files alongside CSS and then browser runs those js and CSS codes and renders the final webpage.